# execute index.html on internet access to server

Tags: html, apache

I'm running Apache on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm Port Forwarding 8080 to my server. I've edited `ports.conf` to `Listen 8080`. I have an `index.html` in `/var/www/html`. when I browse to `MyURL:8080` I get An Index of `/` that shows html as a directory.

If I click the html directory icon, my index.html executes. I looked at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` and `000-default.conf`, they both show `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`. So does `sites-enabled/000-default.conf`.

Any help on what to try next to get the `index.html` to execute on entry to the server would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert on ubuntu's apache configuration, but through some quick searching I found this http://www.ajopaul.com/2010/05/01/ubuntu-apache2-change-default-documentroot-varwww/

Is it necessary to have a trailing "/" on the document root path?

Comment: jhockman, good idea, but it didn't seem to make a difference.  I'm working around the issue by putting my index.html in /var/www rather than in /var/www/html, but that doesn't "right".

Comment: Well that's not good news. I wish I could offer more help in the matter.